# Sqlite data not getting fetching

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I am trying fetch the value from data base But it is not getting 
I am trying this code but didn't get the value ,When i use the Break point on the program
I am having   Longitude,Latitude his data type is double in data base

```
if(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) 
    {
        NSString *sqlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select Longitude,Latitude from Location"];
        const char *sqlStatement = [sqlStr UTF8String];
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            locations = [NSMutableArray array];

            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                int i = sqlite3_step(compiledStatement);
                NSLog(@"%i",i); **//over here i am getting the 101 value in console** And my pointer getting out from here 
                NSString *dLongitude = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3)];
                NSString *dLatitude = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 4)];    
                [locations addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ,%@",dLongitude,dLatitude]];
                NSLog(@"%@",locations);
            }

            result = [locations componentsJoinedByString:@" "]; // same as `fake_location`

            // Get file path here

            NSError *error;
            if ( [result writeToFile:dbPath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error] ) {
                NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }
        }
        // Release the compiled statement from memory
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
```

Comment: I dont understand - what data type longitude and latitude are in database? If it real or double why you use sqlite3_column_text instead of double longitude = sqlite3_column_double(compiledStatement, 3); ???

Comment: I want to store that data into the array                        [locations addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ,%@",dLongitude,dLatitude]];

Comment: Sure, you can do it a bit later if you want. But at first you need to get it from database as double if it double in database. And cast it to the string then and store it in you array.

Comment: can you explain me with code please .

Comment: @Ajay While fetching values from column you need to provide correct column number which starts from 0. In your case you are starting from 3. I guess it is wrong. Try putting 0 and 1 accordingly and try.

Comment: Only masochists use the SQLite C API directly in Objective-C.  [Use FMDB](http://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) (a SQLite wrapper) or [CoreData](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) (an object graph manager) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                    int i = sqlite3_step(compiledStatement);
                    NSLog(@"%i",i); **//over here i am getting the 101 value in console** And my pointer getting out from here 

                    double longitude = sqlite3_column_double(compiledStatement, 3);
                    double latitude = sqlite3_column_double(compiledStatement, 4);

                    NSString *coords = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f,%f",longitude,latitude] autorelease];

                    [locations addObject:coords];
                    NSLog(@"%@",locations);
                }
```

Comment: It show me error [TLocationManager init]':
/Users/HarishYadav/Desktop/JourneyMapper/Journey/TLocationManager.m:88: error: expected ']' before string constant
no '-initWithFormat' method found

Comment: It's work but when it come to  the line  NSString *coords = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f,%f",longitude,latitude] autorelease]; it get crash and My iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications data base get error and database doesn't open   what was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to the following :

```
if(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) 
{
    NSString *sqlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select Longitude,Latitude from UserJourneyLocation"];
    const char *sqlStatement = [sqlStr UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        locations = [NSMutableArray array];

        while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            int i = sqlite3_step(compiledStatement);
         //   NSLog(@"%i",i); / comment this line or use  NSLog(@"%d",i);

         // Make sure your longitude is double in database. else change the fetching value declaration
            // We use 0 for dLongitude instead of 3 because in the select statement, it is the first value to be fetched irrespective of your table structure
            // and same for dLatitude.
           double dLongitude = sqlite3_column_double(compiledStatement, 0);
            double dLatitude = sqlite3_column_double(compiledStatement, 1);    
            [locations addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d ,%d",dLongitude,dLatitude]];
            NSLog(@"%@",locations);
        }

        result = [locations componentsJoinedByString:@" "]; // same as `fake_location`

        // Get file path here

        NSError *error;
        if ( [result writeToFile:dbPath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error] ) {
            NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }
    // Release the compiled statement from memory
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
```

Comment: It's work but when it come to the line NSString *coords = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f,%f",longitude,latitude] autorelease]; it get crash and My iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications data base get error and database doesn't open what was the problem.  But i don't understand why my database get error.it not get open

Comment: Try this : NSString *coords = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f",longitude,latitude];